# XCode system config and unable to access ios keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

Just started learning iOS development through the apple foodtracker tutorial, and already ran into a problem!

I'm on step 3 (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) and even using the completed code supplied by Apple, it runs into a problem.

The code compiles and the UI shows up all fine, but when I select the textbox, the keyboard doesn't show up, and I get a system message that says:

**2017-09-10 16:21:50.772951-0700 FoodTracker[4207:86166] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/mh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F2E7B2AC-1F73-4CAD-BE26-F04EAA1E5C15/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles 2017-09-10 16:21:50.773393-0700 FoodTracker[4207:86166] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.**

It doesn't look like an error, but some kind of system configuration. However, the keyboard never pops up, and if I manually do it via simulator, it doesn't do what the program is supposed to do, which is change the title to whatever I input after I click the button.

Does anyone know why this is? I'm using the latest version of XCode on OSX Sierra. Could it be something I need to configure?

Thanks!

Comment: Your can ignore that log message, it is not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two problems.

First, the keyboard not coming up.  The simulator may be defaulting to use the host keyboard, which behaves the same as if you had a bluetooth keyboard connected to a device.  This means you should be able to enter text directly from your physical keyboard.  When you say you exposed it "manually via simulator", this corresponds to disabling the bluetooth keyboard, so that the displayed keyboard can be tapped to enter characters.

Second, your input is apparently not getting processed.  To diagnose this, I suggest setting breakpoints at any text field delegate methods you have, to see what's coming through,